# Parsing multiple News articles

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have built a program for summarization that utilizes a parser to parse from multiple websites at a time. I extract only `<p>` in each article.

This throws out a lot of random content that is unrelated to the article. I've seen several people who can parse any article perfectly. How can i do it? I am using Beautiful Soup

Comment: Content doesn't have to be in `p` tags, so why would you expect that to work? Perhaps you can reference a website you are trying to target?

Comment: Your question is badly worded. Please have a re-read and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth you trying an existing package like [`python-goose`](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) which does what it sounds like you're asking for, extracting article content from web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is really going to be specific to each website page you want to scrape, so, without knowing the websites of interest, the only thing I could really suggest would be to inspect the page source of each page you want to scrape and look if the article is contained in some html element with a specific attribute (either a unique class, id, or even summary attribute) and then use beautiful soup to get the inner html text from that element